# ORDER BY not working in while() loop, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm making an article list, and I want it to list by "ASC"(Ascending), but its not working.

I've tried the `ORDER BY` and `sort();`, but i think I did the sort(); wrong.

this is the selecting from database part

```
include_once("config.php");
$result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY post_id");
error_reporting(0);
?>
```

and this is the while(); loop

```
<?php while ($entry = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) { ?>
```

I really want it to ascend the list from the id.

if you want to know, basically what i do after the while loop is call the datas from the table using `$entry['datafromdatabase']`

Comment: Can you provide more code? Please add more code & explanation. @dhentris answer should be working fine is you don't add `extra steps`...

Comment: is the column `post_id` the same as the `id` you mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY post_id ASC");
```

it's work for me.

Comment: can you help me with that. Sorry i'm a beginner

Comment: Put array in varible
$entry = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
then write this in your html file 
<?php foreach($result2 as $column) { ?>
<tr> <?php echo $result2[your field]; ?> </tr>
<?php    } ?>

Comment: what's $column?

Comment: That's the same as OP's query. `ORDER BY` defaults to ascending order.